# How can I get a div to be minimum width when it's inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs.

Div A is 100% width
Div B is inside of Div A, it has no width set and has a few words of text inside it

I tried to set the bottom border for Div B so the text appeared underline. However it seems like Div B extends the full width of Div A. Is there any way that I can make Div B just be the width of the text.

Hope my problem is clear.

Thanks,

Comment: any reason you can't use a `span` instead of a `div`?

Answer (score 6):

Divs are block level elements, which means they always expand to 100% of the width of their container.

If you're looking to just put a border around the text, wrap it in an inline element such as a span and apply the border to that span.

Alternatively, use `display:inline` on the div in question, but there's really no point using a div for that purpose

Comment: Good answer. If you need padding and such though you need to use display: inline-block;

Comment: true, but there's no mention of this requirement in the question so I didn't mention it for sake of brevity and simplicity.

Comment: Lol, I've done that all day and keep getting blasted for not being sophisticated enough :/

Comment: haha, don't let those guys fool you, I think simplicity almost always beats sophistication... unless you're at a black tie event

Comment: My thoughts as well. Hehe, black tie.

Answer (score 2):

Add `float: left` to Div B. The width of the `div` will then be determined by the width of the content inside; or in other words, the `div` will "shrink wrap" to its content.

To make Div A [contain](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) Div B properly, you should also add `overflow: hidden` to Div A.

Another option is to use `display: inline-block` on Div B. But in this case, `float` is easier, because `display: inline-block` needs some help to work in IE7.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sfg8Y/

Comment: `float` seems a bit like jumping through hoops no?  `inline` elements do exactly what we want with no extra markup or css declarations.

Comment: @brad: `inline` elements do not allow you to add `margin-top`/`margin-bottom` (amongst other things). To solve that, you need to use `display: inline-block`. My answer covers why it's easier to just a use a float compared to `display: inline-block` (for IE7 compatibility). Even if it does only take `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1` to make it work in IE7. Of course, he might also be fine with a `<span>`, which (per your answer) is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: inline-block` for the inside div.

```css
#A { 
  background: #abc;
}

#B {
   background: #cba;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
    a few words of text inside
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="mydiv">content</div>

div.mydiv
{
     display: inline-block;
     padding-bottom: 1px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```